# Error installing devtools in Dockerfile - devtools package not found?

Tags: r, docker

My Dockerfile aims to install devtools and then use it to install packages listed in the requirements.txt file. The installation of devtools step seems to complete without any errors. However, when the Dockerfile attempts to use devtools to install dependencies mentioned in requirements.txt, it reports that the devtools library is not available.

To investigate the issue, I tried loading the container without installing devtools or requirements.txt. Then, I entered R and installed devtools manually, which worked fine. Therefore, I suspect that the issue is not due to any missing dependencies.

This is my dockerfile:

```
# Use the official R base image as a base
FROM r-base:4.1.2

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
    libxml2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev build-essential

# Install devtools dependencies
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('remotes', 'git2r', 'httr', 'usethis', 'testthat'), repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# Install devtools
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('r-lib/devtools@v2.4.2')"

COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the required packages from the requirements.txt file
RUN R -e "library(devtools)"
RUN R -e "while (length(grep('^ *[a-zA-Z]+ *=[^=]+$', readLines('requirements.txt')))) { \
          req <- read.table('requirements.txt', col.names = c('Package', 'Version'), sep = '=', quote = '', comment.char = '', fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); \
          package <- req$Package[1]; version <- req$Version[1]; \
          message(sprintf('Installing package %s with version %s', package, version)); \
          devtools::install_version(package, version = version, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/'); \
          system(sprintf('sed -i.bak \'/^ *%s *=/d\' requirements.txt', package)); \
        }"
```

The last part of the dockerfile is installing R packages specified in a requirements.txt file using the devtools package.

The first line of the code RUN R -e "library(devtools)" loads the devtools library, which is a package for developing and installing other R packages.

The second line of the code starts a while loop that reads each line of the requirements.txt file and installs the specified package and version using the devtools::install_version() function.

The code then removes the installed package and its version from the requirements.txt file using the `system(sprintf('sed -i.bak \'/^ *%s *=/d\' requirements.txt', package));` command.

The while loop continues until all the packages listed in the requirements.txt file have been installed.

This is requirements.txt:

```
DBI=1.1.3
dotenv=1.0.3
httr=1.4.3
jsonlite=1.8.0
magrittr=2.0.3
pool=1.0.1
readr=2.1.2
RMySQL=0.10.23
usethis=2.1.6
base=4.1.2
datasets=4.1.2
graphics=4.1.2
grDevices=4.1.2
methods=4.1.2
stats=4.1.2
utils=4.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE @ 2023-03-27:

As @Frank mentioned, it's better reads `reauirements.txt` as a data frame inside the `RUN R -e` session:

```
library(devtools)
req <- read.table('requirements.txt', col.names = c('Package', 'Version'), sep = '=', quote = '', comment.char = '', fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:nrow(req)) {
  package <- req[i, 'Package']
  version <- req[i, 'Version']
  message(sprintf('Installing package %s with version %s', package, version))
  devtools::install_version(package, version = version, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')
}
```

## Original answer:

Maybe try this?

```
RUN R -e "library(devtools); while (length(grep('^ *[a-zA-Z]+ *=[^=]+$', readLines('requirements.txt')))) { \
          req <- read.table('requirements.txt', col.names = c('Package', 'Version'), sep = '=', quote = '', comment.char = '', fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); \
          package <- req$Package[1]; version <- req$Version[1]; \
          message(sprintf('Installing package %s with version %s', package, version)); \
          devtools::install_version(package, version = version, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/'); \
          system(sprintf('sed -i.bak \'/^ *%s *=/d\' requirements.txt', package)); \
        }"
```

Comment: Also, maybe [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) is better for R compared to your conda-styled `requirements.txt`

Comment: This is exactly the problem.  The first session attached `devtools`, and the second session tried to use it.  It doesn't stay attached.

Comment: I got an error: ```#11 2.222 Error in archive[[package]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
#11 2.222 Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> download_version_url -> package_find_archives
#11 2.222 Execution halted
```

Comment: This code works, if you update your answer I'll mark complete:
```RUN R -e "library(devtools); \
        req <- read.table('requirements.txt', col.names = c('Package', 'Version'), sep = '=', quote = '', comment.char = '', fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); \
        for (i in 1:nrow(req)) { \
          package <- req[i, 'Package']; version <- req[i, 'Version']; \
          message(sprintf('Installing package %s with version %s', package, version)); \
          devtools::install_version(package, version = version, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/'); \
        }"```